# Coproduct in the category of metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, category-theory

While discussing categories without coproducts, we stumbled with the category $\mathbf{Met}$ that takes metric spaces as its objects and short maps as its morphisms. It is claimed that $\mathbf{Met}$ does not have coproducts. I'm puzzled since the disjoint union of metric spaces is also a metric space so that would make it a candidate for the coproduct in the category but I'm unable to see why it fails to be one. Any ideas?

Comment: In the disjoint union, what is the distance $d(x_1,x_2)$ for $x_1\in X_1$ and $x_2 \in X_2$? 't Seems nontrivial to me.

Comment: Coproducts exist if the distance is allowed to take the value $\infty$

Comment: I'll just note to this old question that the root issue here is a confusion between the category of metric spaces and the category of metrizable spaces, and these are not the same. The category of metrizable spaces has coproducts (assuming ZFC), but the category of metric spaces does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy argument proceeds by contradiction: Suppose that there were coproducts, and consider $X+Y$ for nonempty $X,Y$. Now consider the metric spaces $2_N =\{-N,N\} \subseteq \Bbb R$ together with the (obviously short) maps $$\begin{align}+&:X \to 2_N, x \mapsto N\\-&:Y\to2_N,y\mapsto -N\end{align}$$

Then $d(+(x),-(y)) = 2N$ for arbitrary $x,y,N$; it is easy to see that this contradicts the simultaneous shortness of *all* induced maps $X+Y\to 2_N$ (finitely many go fine, but the distance between $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ in $X+Y$ needs to be infinite to make them all short).

Therefore, the coproduct $X+Y$ cannot exist. The fundamental reason behind this is the inability to make the distance between $X$ and $Y$ large enough.

Comment: If I got it right, then the key is to realize that the distance between points $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ in $X+Y$, say $d(x,y)$, is finite so we can find some $N \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $N > d(x,y)$. With such an $N$, for the metric space $2_N$, it would be impossible to find a short map having the universal property for coproducts. 

Really compelling argument, thanks!

Comment: @egomezcana That is exactly right, and you're welcome :).

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: I wrote this answer a few seconds before Lord_Farin's answer appeared, so in the first sentence below I was referring to his comment on the question, not to his answer. I guess I'll keep this here for the comment about allowing $\infty$ as a distance, but regard this more as a comment now that he's posted a full proof.

---

@Lord_Farin hit on the difficulty. The easiest way to see what goes wrong is to try to make the coproduct of a point with itself: you might think it's two points, but at what distance? If the distance is $d$, the universal property fails for maps from this coproduct to any space with some pair of points at a distance greater than $d$.

If you change the definition of metric slightly to allow $d(x_1,x_2)=\infty$, then the resulting category of slightly generalized metrics spaces and short maps does have coproducts: in the coproduct of $X_1$ and $X_2$ you make the distance from points of $X_1$ to $X_2$ infinite.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! It was very useful to understand the one provided by Lord_Farin, I just took $X=Y=\{\ast\}$ and everything ran smoothly. Also, I find very interesting that if you allow infinite distances, the category has coproducts.